# Modelchoicefield save in database django

Tags: python, django, model, modelchoicefield

I want to create a webapp for managing a library .i create the book and the category model.the category is the class of the book 'history literature ..ect' ,i want the category appears as options when adding the book .so i put it in `ModelChoiceField`,but when i try to save the value of `ModelChoiceField` in database, it does not.

here is the code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Livre(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    num_category=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    auteur=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    nombre_copie=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)
    publisher=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import  forms
from . import models
from project.models import Category

class Ajouterlivre(forms.Form):
    titre = forms.CharField(max_length=100)  
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.values_list('name', flat=True))
    auteur = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    nombre_copie = forms.IntegerField()
    publisher = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
def Ajoutlivre(request):

    if request.method== 'POST':
        form=forms.Ajouterlivre(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           objt=Livre()
           objt.titre = form.cleaned_data['titre']
           objt.category= form.cleaned_data['category']
           objt.auteur = form.cleaned_data['auteur']
           objt.nombre_copie = form.cleaned_data['nombre_copie']
           objt.publisher = form.cleaned_data['publisher']
           objt.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form=forms.Ajouterlivre()
    return render(request,'livre/ajout-livre.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

> ModelchoiceField requires queryset returning dictionary and not tuples, when you use values_list its returns a tuples.
> so you have to change the category (**) line in your code to work.

```
class Ajouterlivre(forms.Form):
    titre = forms.CharField(max_length=100)  
    **category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())**
    auteur = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    nombre_copie = forms.IntegerField()
    publisher = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

> Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.